# Upgrade the CoreData in Existing Application when installing the new version of application

Tags: ios, ios4, core-data, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-data-migration

Upon installing the new SDK into our application, I attempted to run the app, overwriting an existing application. I received an exception, the relevant stack trace of which is below:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:

`This NSPersistentStoreCoordinator has no persistent stores. It cannot perform a save operation.`

But when i tried after uninstalled my application it is worked fine. I don't want to uninstall whenever i installing the new build what is the solution for this?

Comment: Did you make any changes to your Entity?

Comment: Yes, Sometimes i added new entities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to support Data Migration.  See this related question: 
[I keep on getting “save operation failure” after any change on my XCode Data Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091228/i-keep-on-getting-save-operation-failure-after-any-change-on-my-xcode-data-mode)

and the relevant Apple docs:
[Initiating the Migration Process](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmInitiating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005509-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

I is because you change the Core Data , maybe you add/modify/delete some entities, you need tyr the Data Migration , or delete it.